# How to add unmanaged dependency in play 2 project running on heroku

Tags: maven, heroku, playframework-2.3

I am trying to add a dependency to my play 2 project running on Heroku.

I have read this:https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/SBTDependencies and  I have tried both adding a managed and unmanaged dependency.

When I try adding an unmanaged dependency, I get the following error:

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.cloudbees.thirdparty#zendesk-java-client;0.2.5-SNAPSHOT: not found
```

Here is the warning messages:

```
remote:        [warn]   module not found: com.cloudbees.thirdparty#zendesk-java-client;0.2.5-SNAPSHOT
remote:        [warn] ==== local: tried
remote:        [warn]   /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/.sbt_home/.ivy2/local/com.cloudbees.thirdparty/zendesk-java-client/0.2.5-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
remote:        [warn] ==== public: tried
remote:        [warn]           http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/cloudbees/thirdparty/zendesk-java-client/0.2.5-SNAPSHOT/zendesk-java-client-0.2.5-SNAPSHOT.pom
remote:        [warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
remote:        [warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/cloudbees/thirdparty/zendesk-java-client/0.2.5-SNAPSHOT/zendesk-java-client-0.2.5-SNAPSHOT.pom
remote:        [warn] ==== Local Maven Repository: tried
remote:        [warn]   file:///Users/lars/.m2/repository/com/cloudbees/thirdparty/zendesk-java-client/0.2.5-SNAPSHOT/zendesk-java-client-0.2.5-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

So, it appears as it is looking in the maven repo on my computer locally. I am assuming this folder does not exist on Heroku.

I have added the .jar-file to a folder called lib/ in my project.

Here is my build.sbt-file:

```
name := """name here"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1201-jdbc41",
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaWs
)
```

Does anybody have any suggestions on what to try out? Can there be that the heroku-project has not been cleaned properly and some old settings are hanging?

Thanks.

Comment: By default SBT on heroku does not run the ```clean``` task before building your project. You can enforce this by adding a setting to heroku: ```heroku config:set SBT_CLEAN=true```

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the answer. I was pushing the wrong branch.

I followed the tutorial blindly, writing:

> git push heroku master

which pushed my master branch to heroku.

I should have wrote

> git push heroku dev:master

which pushed my dev branch to heroku instead. This solved the question.